# Не выводится в списке мною созданный класс

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios8

Началась проблема совсем не давно, eсли я создаю новый класс то при создании нового объекта этого класса приходится присать его имя целиком.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобной проблемой.

Comment: обещать не берусь, но мне кажется, если удалить derived data и вызвать таким образом реиндексацию, должно сработать.

Comment: Эта проблема последней версии  x-code, derived data чистил, после запуска она опять забивается...

Answer (score 0):

А по-моему тут все в порядке вещей или я что-то не так понимаю. Приведу пример создания объекта в Objective-C:

```
VMStudent *objectVMStudent = [VMStudent new];
```

Comment: Как видите, синтаксис Objective-C подразумевает указание имени класса при создании объекта.